# custom Resource folder names for layout,drawable .. in android

Tags: android, resources, directory, names

I have 2 different functionality to be implemented as part of a single application.

They have different screen flows and BL to be implemented but a single apk,so it is transparent to the end user.

I have 100 screens for each of the flow,so can I have custom folder names in the resources directory for easy maintenance and loose coupling.

eg: res
     -layout
     -layout_savings
     -layout_checking

-drawable

-drawable_savings

-drawable_cheking

currently we have only the following structure
    res

```
 -layout

 -layout-land 
 -drawable
 -values
```

Will there be any problem while generating the R.java file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for what you need , i suggest you to use the assets directory instead of res. in assets dir you can sort your files anyway you like (dir name/filename) . You access them with AssetManager.

this require a little change in code but i think this is the only way if you want to sort your file like that , res folder doesn't allow custom directory names.

(Or of course you can store files in the sdcard)

Comment: TQ for your sugesstion eephyne,I considered that soultion before,but 1 assets doesn't have Id's and are not used during R.java generation  2.Each time I have to use AssetManager and I/O stream to use the assets . Currently we can have follwing type of folder name allowed,drawable-en-notouch-12key ,so was thinking if we have any custom qualifiers allowed in the naming convention used in resources.

Comment: yes assets doesn't have ID , but that's the only way i see (except using sdcard) if you want custom folder , the res folder has a strict policy for naming the folder like you see and doesn't allow custom name , they're here just for separate some ressource following rules (language,density,etc).